# Loop through a chain of shell scripts to verify if they are running, before executing a new one

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, grep

I'd like to loop through all the shell scripts listed inside an array, before printing out the "No scripts are running" message.

The expected behavior is that once the loop catches a script that's running, it waits for 5 seconds, then it starts the loop from the beginning (0 index in the array). This way even if any of the previous scripts from the beginning of the chain would start up in the meantime, the loop should still catch it.

```
#!/bin/bash

shellScripts=('amirunner.sh' 'btest.sh' 'test1.sh' 'whatisthis.sh')
shellScriptsLength=${#shellScripts[@]}
indexCounter=0

for shellScriptsLength in ${shellScripts[@]}
    do 
        if pgrep -x ${shellScripts[indexCounter]} >/dev/null
        then
            echo "${shellScripts[indexCounter]}" "is running"
            sleep 5
            let "indexCounter=0"
        else
            let "indexCounter+=1"       
        fi
    done

echo "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"
```

If non of the listed shell scripts are running, it should print "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"

The problem I'm facing is that the loop won't go through the entire array.
Sometimes when all the listed scripts are running except the first one for example, the loop still ends with the "No scripts are running" message. The script names are spelled correctly.

In this example I am starting all 4 scripts, waiting for 15 seconds, and killing the "amirunner.sh" script. I'm getting the following output:

```
amirunner.sh is running
amirunner.sh is running
amirunner.sh is running
No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now
```

Comment: your loop will run as many times as your array elements.  `for shellScriptsLength in ${shellScripts[@]}` that's 4 times and matches your observation.

Comment: Ah, thank you, you are right. I guess if I add a another loop outside this loop, that runs by the indexCounter, that might do the trick. I was sure it's caused by a trivial logic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help everyone.

As karakfa pointed out, the problem in the logic was, that the indexCounter did not function as intended to control the state of the loop. Ed Morton's solution worked well to keep the main script alive, but it didn't repeat the loop from the beginning, once the loop caught a running script, so at the end I decided to change the **for loop** into a **while loop**, and now the output is exactly what's expected.

```
#!/bin/bash

shellScripts=('amirunner.sh' 'btest.sh' 'test1.sh' 'whatisthis.sh')
shellScriptsLength=${#shellScripts[@]}
indexCounter=0

while ((indexCounter < shellScriptsLength)) 
  do
    if pgrep -x ${shellScripts[indexCounter]} >/dev/null
      then
        echo "${shellScripts[indexCounter]} is running"
        sleep 2
        indexCounter=0
    else
      let "indexCounter+=1"
    fi
done

echo "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `shellScriptsLength`on every iteration of the loop but never using it. Meanwhile you're indexing `shellScripts` by `0` inside the loop and if the associated process isn't running you're going to sleep and leaving indexCouter as 0 for the next time around.

I think this might be what you're trying to do (untested but should be closer to working):

```
#!/bin/bash

shellScripts=('amirunner.sh' 'btest.sh' 'test1.sh' 'whatisthis.sh')
shellScriptsLength=${#shellScripts[@]}
indexCounter=0

for (( indexCounter=0; indexCounter<=shellScriptsLength; indexCounter++ )); do
    shellScript="${shellScripts[$indexCounter]}"
    if pgrep -x "$shellScript" >/dev/null; then
        echo "$shellScript is running"
        sleep 5
        (( indexCounter = -1 ))
    fi
done

echo "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, this is the closest to the actual solution. With this one the loop indeed keeps checking if the listed scripts are running, however it ignores the first script, even if it's running, and it does not go back to the beginning of the cycle if any of the other scripts are running. Your solution will be very helpful to repair mine. I'll post the repaired version when it's done. Cheers

Comment: AH, right, the `indexCounter++` at the end of the `for` will set it to 1 immediately after I set it to zero within the loop.  I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I share the solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shellScripts=('amirunner.sh' 'btest.sh' 'test1.sh' 'whatisthis.sh')
shellScriptsLength=${#shellScripts[@]}
notRunningCounter=0

for thisShell in ${shellScripts[@]}
    do 
        if pgrep -x $thisShell >/dev/null
        then
            echo "$thisShell is running"
        else
            let "notRunningCounter+=1"
        fi
    done
if test $notRunningCounter -eq $shellScriptsLength
then
    echo "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"
fi
```

This code verify is each process in list is running. If a process is running then print a message. Finally, after verify all process, if non of these are running,  the message: "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now" is printed.

Please, tell me is this the solution you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. Unfortunately this solution does not meet the expected outcome. This version only goes trough the array once, than stops, no matter if the scripts are running or not, it just displays their status. The loop should keep starting from the beginning until all the shell scripts on the list has stopped running.

Answer (score 0):

use `&&`
everything after `&&` will be evaluated only if the previous success (exit 0)
as opposite `||`
if you want to execute the next command no matter what use `;`
and the next command will be executed no matter what happen to the previous command.

```
    # // the script list could be auto generated using `ls -1`
    for i in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh ; do
       $i
       # // if the exit code is not 0 then exit
       [[ $? -eq 0 ]] || exit 1
       # // end of the loop
    done
```

you can also use for loop just to build the string for `eval` to evaluate.

```
    # // the script list could be auto generated using `ls -1`
    COMMAND=""
    for i in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh ; do
       COMMAND=" $COMMAND && $i "
    done
    eval "$COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script. Now verify if any of element in script list are running, show a message and restart the list verification again.

I believe this is you need:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shellScripts=('amirunner.sh' 'btest.sh' 'test1.sh' 'whatisthis.sh')
shellScriptsLength=${#shellScripts[@]}
notRunningCounter=0
indexCounter=0;
for ((indexCounter=0; indexCounter<shellScriptsLength; indexCounter++))
do
    thisShell=${shellScripts[$indexCounter]};
        if pgrep -x $thisShell >/dev/null;
        then
            echo "$thisShell is running"
        else
            let "notRunningCounter+=1"

        fi

    #if all process were checked and one or more were running, restart to check all in the next iterations
    if  test $indexCounter -eq $((shellScriptsLength-1)) && test $notRunningCounter  -lt $shellScriptsLength
    then
        indexCounter=-1
        notRunningCounter=0
        echo "Process check was restarted."
        echo "-----------------"
        sleep 5     
    fi

done

if test $notRunningCounter -eq $shellScriptsLength
then
    echo "No scripts are running, executing somethingsomething.sh now"
fi
```